# SQL error when adding new scaffold in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I made a new scaffold

```
rails generate scaffold hobbies description:text
```

and deleted it because I wanted to add more fields

```
rails destroy scaffold hobbies
```

then readded it

```
rails generate scaffold hobbies description:text schedule:text
```

Now, when I run rake db:migrate, I get this error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: table "hobbies" already exists: CREATE TABLE "hobbies" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255), "description" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) /Users/Aeip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

Comment: Looks like you already have this table. Try to delete it manualy, and run again.

Comment: afurm, how do I delete the table? Doesn't destroying the scaffold do that?

Comment: Try removing it from `schema.rb`

Comment: Okay,this has worked. It is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

do `rails d scaffold hobbies description:text`

then `rails generate scaffold hobbies description:text schedule:text`

Answer (score 0):

```
$> bundle exec rake db:drop db:create # caution: it destroys your database
```

Then run the generator again

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't work everytime you want to undo a migration but for your scenario it works just as fine since all you need to do is to drop the hobbies table.

Take note of the timestamp of the migration file when you ran the generator

```
rails generate scaffold hobbies description:text schedule:text
>> invoice active_record
>> create    db/migrate/20140309162533_create_hobbies.rb
```

Since you want to delete the hobbies table, you need to run the `down` version of the migration and you can do that using rake `db:migrate:down`.  Be sure to pass the timestamp of the migration you want to run.

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20140309162533
```